# rails g controller コマンドでアプリケーションディレクトリ外に生成を試みてしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse

OS: windows8.1
eclipse3.8
ruby 2.1.6 32bit版
Rails 4.1.10

上記環境でローカルで開発を進めています。
eclipse上でrailsプロジェクトを作成し、ターミナルからこのディレクトリ内でrails new . の後、
rails g controller hoge/fuga -helper false -assets false
としたところ、下記実行されました。

```
  create  app/controllers/hoge/fuga_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/hoge/fuga
  invoke  rspec
  create    spec/controllers/hoge/fuga_controller_spec.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/api/login_helper.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/helpers/hoge/fuga_helper_spec.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    js
  create      app/assets/javascripts/hoge/fuga.js
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/hoge/fuga.css.scss
```

しかし、期待したディレクトリの中に何も生成されていませんでした。

何故かeclipseのインストールディレクトリからのパスに生成を試みたようで、
C:/eclipse/app/controllers/hoge/fuga_controller.rb となったようです。
ただし、これもまた該当のディレクトリには何のファイルも生成されていませんでした。

また、そもそもhelperとassetsは生成しないように指示したにもかかわらず、
create,invokeが走っており、これも不可解です。

正しく、現在のrailsプロジェクト内でgenerateが実行されるようにするためには
単純にrailsプロジェクトを作成しgenerateコマンドを実行する以外に何かあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> また、そもそもhelperとassetsは生成しないように指示したにもかかわらず、
>   create,invokeが走っており、これも不可解です。

まずここだけ。
--no-helper --no-assets ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！今まさに自分でも間違っていることに気付きまして。。お恥ずかしい質問をしてしまい情けないです。「-helper false -assets false」は「--helper false --assets false」の誤りで、こちらで実行したところ意図したとおりに生成されました。--no-helper --no-assetsという記述もできるのですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ちゃんと生成されたようでよかったです。私のほうでも再現しましたが…ret:0で正常終了したように見えるのは、ヤだなぁ…。